# How can I make this request

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

What I had: An application that when you opened, it showed you a map with 3 buttons that said, "Restaurant", "Hospitals","Bars", and once clicked one of them they showed you this places nearby

What I have: For aesthetic questions an app that when you open, it shows you a RecyclerView with images, and when you click one of these images takes you to a map with your current position.

What I want: That when I click on one of the images of the RecyclerView for example Restaurants, it show a map with the restaurants near me, but making this request from the OnClickListener that I have in my RecyclerView's Adapter on the OnBindViewHolder() method

My Question: How do I make this request if the elements such as Latitude and Longitude are in another Activity and also within a Method called OnMapReady () in which I used to make the request with the buttons I had initially. Please I would appreciate the answers with code examples, I am still not very good at programming and there are millions of terms that I do not understand, thanks in advance

My RecyclerView and where I want to make the request

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.etiNombre.setText(listalugares.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());

        holder.foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position == 0){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Where I used to make my request

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {//esta funcion es llamada cuando el mapa esta listo para usarse(1- locacion)
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);//esto es lo que que dice de que forma queremos que se vea el mapa

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        Button btnRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRestaurant);
        btnRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String Restaurant = "restaurant";
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
                mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data from an activity to another, you'll have to use [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)'s `extras` field. It's a `Bundle` (a key/value data-structure) where you can store everything you want (with size constraints, so it's usually a good idea to pass only IDs or stuff like that, not the actual data).

What you can do here is: in your adapter's `onClick` method, add an extra field to the `Intent`, containing the information type you want to display (either restaurant, bar or hospital). Then, in your second activity (the one containing the map), in the `onCreate` method, read the field from the `Intent`. Then you can still place your Nearby Places request in the `onMapReady` method, using the field to determine which type you're requesting, instead of depending on a specific button click event.

Comment: I really appreciate that you have answered my question, but I am afraid that I still don't understand what to do, I would really appreciate an Example code, and again, thanks for your answer